# I need to add a number from right to left in the decimal value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display decimal value in calculator using javascript.
if i click any buttons in the calculator, the button value added to decimal value from the right to left and it should be display in the screen.
For Eg: **`The default value is 0.00 if i click 2, it should be 0.02 and if i click 3, it should be 0.23 and if i click 4, it should be 2.34 and if i click 5, it should be 23.45 and so on.`**

Comment: Cool! What have you tried? Is this for a webpage, a console application, where should the text show up as the user types?

Comment: it is for web page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you have to multiply the stored value by 10 and divide the input value by 100 and sum both the result

Comment: @SonalBorkar ... you don't necessarily know that. this could be as simple as applying a CSS property on an input field

Comment: @Katie.Sun How you handle css property on button click without JS? There is no input field.

Comment: I'm sorry, this really isn't something I can help with unless you post some code. There are way too many unknowns here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
let number = 0;

// Returns the new value in case you need it to display in console
// and updates the number variable with the new value.
function addNumberRightToLeft(value) {
  number = ((number * 10) + (value / 100)).toFixed(2);
  return number;
}

console.log(addNumberRightToLeft(5)); // Shows '0.05' in console and updates number variable, so it is now '0.05'.

// or

addNumberRightToLeft(5); // Does not print to console but updates number variable, so it is now '0.55'.
```

or even use ES6 arrow functions and without side effects (as suggested by Nika):

```
const addNumberRightToLeft = (p, v) => ((p * 10) + (v / 100)).toFixed(2);
```

where `p` is the last value returned and `v` is what you want to add. In action:

```
let number = 0;

number = addNumberRightToLeft(number, 5); // 0.05
number = addNumberRightToLeft(number, 5); // 0.55
```

Comment: ES6 without side effects: `const addNumberRightToLeft = (p, v) => ((p * 10) + (v / 100)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: where `p` is last value returned and `v` is what you want to add as a sum.

Comment: @Nika, could I add it to the answer?

Comment: of course! no problem :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Like below: resultNum should be first initialize as 0.00;

```
function showCalc(inputNum)
 {

var a = resultNum * 10.00;

var b = inputNum / 100;

resultNum = a + b;

 return resultNum;

 }
```

Comment: You're going to want to add `toFixed(2)` to this. Otherwise you'll get bit by JavaScript math and end up with a.e. `0.12000001`

Comment: Please do not answer (and hence encourage) zero-effort questions.